# Sharing data between repos/modules in Angular 6 multi-repo architecture

Tags: angular, architecture

I am tasked with designing an Angular application in a multi/micro-repo structure so that the smaller Angular feature components will be broken down into individual repos and can be consumed by React apps in a React wrapper.

The requirement is that the feature components will need to be re-usable across different businesses units and datasets. Essentially making some of our features shared re-usable components. This means that the service logic of fetching data needs to be an input rather than an embedded service. Same for logos, branding, styling, HTML items, etc. Also, we want to make a clear distinction of the mapping of dev teams to features.

Because of this I expect to only be able to use inputs for getting this data.

Question 1: Have I made a correct assumption in that Angular input decorators are the best way to go?

Question 2: Has anyone else taken this approach and if so can you please share your thoughts?

Example using simple logo

Feature module *.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
...
export class HeaderComponent {
  @Input() logo: string;
  ..
}
```

Consuming module *.html

```
<app-header [logo]="logo"></app-header>
```